# Replace text on click with the text from the link that has been clicked

Tags: jquery, loops, text, each

```
<ul class="filter">
<li>
<span class="filtertext"><span>Filter</span></span>
<ul class="dropdown">
<li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)">All</a</li>

<li><a href="#">Administrative Associates</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Associate Principals</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Associates</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Chief Financial Officer</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Directors</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Principals</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Senior Associates</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Staff</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
```

I have a filter set up with Quicksand and the above list is displaying a dropdown on my site. What I am trying to do is replace the text "Filter" that is in the  tag with text from whatever category is selected.

I have this working, however, it only does it the first time. I have a feeling I need to implement something like .each() but can't seem to figure out where exactly I should put it. Following is my jQuery code:

```
$('ul.dropdown li a').click(function (){
$('span.filtertext span').replaceWith( $(this).html() );
});
```

Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it only work the first time is because you're using `replaceWith`, which actually removes the element; the next time your function runs, `$('span.filtertext span')` can't find anything.

Use this instead (adds caching too):

```
var $filtertext = $('span.filtertext span');
$('ul.dropdown li a').click(function () {
    $filtertext.text( $(this).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to change the text, you should use this :

```
$('ul.dropdown li a').click(function (){ 
    $('span.filtertext span').html( $(this).text() );
});
```

Because if you use `replaceWith` to replace the `span`, there is no object matching `'span.filtertext span'` after the replacement...

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery's .text() instead.

Works at http://jsfiddle.net/6kTQ5/

Try this.

```
$('ul.dropdown li a').click(function (){
    $('span.filtertext span').text( $(this).text() );
});​
```

Comment: Just curious as I'm fairly new to jQuery... what's the reasoning behind using .text() instead of .html()? More efficient?